# A Simple Helper Class doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Sorry for asking such a simple question but I lost really long time trying to solve this. At the end, I decide to ask you.

Let's start with the code base :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace Navigation.Helpers
{
    public static class NavigationBarSE
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString RenderNavigationBarSE(this HtmlHelper helper, String[] includes)
        {
            return new MvcHtmlString("Y U no Work??");
            //NavTypeSE res = new NavTypeSE(includes);
            //String ress = res.toString();
            //return new MvcHtmlString(ress);

        }    
    }
}
```

In the original form, this helper needs to return a String that produced by the NavTypeSE class. But in the end, to get a result, I only want it to return a String for me... But it didn't do that...

Before you ask, I can say that,

```
<add namespace="Navigation.Helpers"/>
```

exists in my Web.config file in Views folder.

For detailed information, my NavTypeSE class as below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Navigation.Helpers
{
    //Creates a Navigation Menu Type which includes Previous, Next and Validate Buttons
        public class NavTypeSE
        {
        Boolean pr, nt, vld;
        Boolean Previous { get; set; }
        Boolean Next { get; set; }
        Boolean Validate { get; set; }
        public NavTypeSE(Boolean Previous, Boolean Next, Boolean Validate)
        {
            this.pr = Previous;
            this.nt = Next;
            this.vld = Validate;
        }
        public NavTypeSE() { }

        public NavTypeSE(String[] inc)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<inc.Length; i++)//foreach (String s in inc)
            {
                String s = inc[i]; // Don't need for foreach method.
                if (s.Equals("previous")||s.Equals("Previous"))
                {
                    this.pr = true;
                }
                else if (s.Equals("next") || s.Equals("Next"))
                {
                    this.nt = true;
                }
                else if (s.Equals("validate") || s.Equals("Validate"))
                {
                    this.vld = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.pr = false; this.nt = false; this.vld = false;
                }
            }

        public String toString()
        {
            return "Previous: " + this.pr + ", Next: " + this.nt + ", Validate: " + this.vld;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, in my View, I call this Helper like below :

```
@{
    String[] str = new String[] { "Previous", "next", "Validate" };
    Html.RenderNavigationBarSE(str);
}
```

This is just a base for a project. And I'm starter level in both C# and ASP.NET MVC Platform. Sorry for spending your time.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Won't the page compile (because it can't find the helper method), or is it just empty and doesnt your string show up? What is actually going wrong?

Comment: unrelated to the programming: you don't need to apologize (twice even) about asking a question. It's kind of what the whole site is built on :)

Comment: @RenéWolferink : There is no response. No error, nothing about compiling problem. It doesn't show anything! It makes me really mad. Because an another version of this class successfully working! :)

Comment: @hometoast : I can't stop myself feeling bad because of asking such a silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RenderNavigationBarSE` writes nothing into the Response just returns a `MvcHtmlString`.

So you need to put an `@` before the method call to tell Razor engine that you want to write the returned `MvcHtmlString` into the response (otherwise inside a code block it just executes your method and throws away the returned value)

```
@{
    String[] str = new String[] { "Previous", "next", "Validate" };
}

@Html.RenderNavigationBarSE(str);
```

You can read more about the Razor syntax:

- [Introduction to ASP.NET Web Programming Using the Razor Syntax (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax)
- There is also a [C# Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)

Comment: Great! Thanks for help...

I tried
`code`
    @String....
    @Html.Render..
`code`

with two "@" symbols but it didn't work. So I thought that when I put them into the same pharantesis, it must work! :)

Really appreciated!

Comment: I will continue to the coding with MVC 4 after learning the details of Razor Synax, I understood that. 

Thanks for everything.